# record command history in linux continuously

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-history

Commands typed in Linux **Terminal**(my OS is *Ubuntu18*) are not saving if my Linux machine is *abruptly* closed.
For example, I have a *VirtualBox Ubuntu18 VM*. I worked for few minutes in which I executed 50 command. These commands will save in ***.bash_history*** file only if I type ***exit*** command but will not save if my machine is abruptly shutdown.(*I agree that we always take care of our system, but I want consider even this corner case where in I should not loose anything*)

What I am trying to find a way is, if I type a command in Terminal(it could be any account and any tty), entered command should record immediately to a file or to *.bash_history*. I don't care if its a failed command or repeatable(duplicate) command.

I have tried script tool either and no luck.
Also tried to use a function that I found other method and save in ***.bashrc***. It also dint work:

```
log_bash_persistent_history()
{
  [[
    $(history 1) =~ ^\ *[0-9]+\ +([^\ ]+\ [^\ ]+)\ +(.*)$
  ]]
  local date_part="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  local command_part="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  if [ "$command_part" != "$PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST" ]
  then
    echo $date_part "|" "$command_part" >> ~/.persistent_history
    export PERSISTENT_HISTORY_LAST="$command_part"
  fi
}
# Stuff to do on PROMPT_COMMAND
run_on_prompt_command()
{
    log_bash_persistent_history
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="run_on_prompt_command"
```

Any other ideas??

Comment: `PS1=$(history -w)`? If you want to write to `.bash_history` then what's up with `~/.persistent_history`?

Comment: My intention here is to save entered command on terminal immediately. So found a solution in internet and tried it as their description looks similar to my problem. Said that I am not keen about `.persistent_history`

Comment: I have tried using `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a $HISTFILE; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` but no luck

Comment: Rebuild bash with O_SYNC